# Regular expression for tags but excluding the attributes

Tags: regex, tags

I work in video game localisation and our CAT tool uses Regular Expressions to detect the tags. Usually, they are enclosed by [], so we use [(.*?)] to identify them. The CAT tool then imports this with a tag format, which means the translators cannot edit/break the tag or delete it without a warning.

However, we have a project that contains a Gender tag with attributes that we need to translate. The tag is the following:

```
[Gender: "male", "female"]
```

The idea is whether there is a tag that can identify the whole segment as one entity, but leaving male and female out. We used these three (added some spaces between commas and square brackets to make the \ visible, sorry if it's confusing):

```
\ [Gender\: \"

\"\ , \"

\"\ ]
```

However, it might create issues with text as well in sentences like:
They said "No, we don't", "We want more", etc.

The `", "` would be detected as a tag unnecessarily.

Is there a way to have one unique regular expression to avoid this? If so, would it be possible to have one if there are more translatable elements or is there a limit? `I.e.: [Gender: "male", "female", "neutral"]`

Thank you very much in advance!

Update: For reference, I've attached the Regex settings. On the bottom side you see how the program uses them to create the tags. The red coloured elements are converted into objects instead of text. That way translators cannot break the tag nor forget to add it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww5vi.jpg)

Comment: I'm not familliar with cat tools? Do you get an option to put in captured group?
See my quick test here. https://regex101.com/r/xFvsCe/1/
(look at the substitution tab)

Comment: Hi Springbo! Thanks for your contribution, I have attached an image of the program to the initial post for clarification. I tested the regular expression you provide and I am afraid it didn't work, none of the text was marked as red and recognised as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok based on your picture I think a better approach would be to make multiple regular expressions. Since it looks like you can apply multiple rules

One to match normal tags (notice how it only matches these)

```
\[([^:\"])+\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/xFvsCe/3

For the segments with multiple translatable elements we need a couple of things.

First match the start of those elements

```
\[([^:\n]+: ?\")
```

https://regex101.com/r/q4Wgdu/2

Then one to tag the comma separators

```
(?<=[^\]])(\", ?\")
```

https://regex101.com/r/U9krdh/2

And finally one to match the end of the segments

```
(?<=[^\]]*?)\"\]
```

https://regex101.com/r/FkgOOx/2

You might need to change the syntax depending on what kindof regex flavour the program uses. The last two regexes uses positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) which might have a slightly different syntax. Or perhaps not even supported.

Hope it helps

Edit: If the rules are applied on top of eathother this will probably not work since I assume the input text will be the same everytime it's fed to a rule. But maybe this can be configured in the filter dropdown?